# Mock a Different class which is used in the class under test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermock, easymock

How can I mock a class which is used in another class using only powerMock or EasyMock,I can only use this two frameworks ,I know we can use Mockito but as our codebase contains only easymock and powermock library I have to stick the two frameworks only .

I have below code ( I am using powerMock )

```
public class ClassUnderTest {

   public void getRecord() {
      System.out.println("1: In getRecord \n");
      System.out.println("\n 3:"+SecondClass.getVoidCall());
      System.out.println("\n 4: In getRecord over \n");
   }
}
```

I want to mock the method SecondClass.getVoidCall() .

```
public class ArpitSecondClass {


   public static int  getVoidCall() {
      System.out.println("\n 2: In ArpitSecondClass getVoidCall for kv testing\n");
      return 10;
   }
}
```

My Unit Test code is

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(TestArpit.class)
public class UniteTestClass {

   @Test
   public void testMock() throws Exception {
      SecondClass class2 = createMock(SecondClass.class);
      expect(class2.getVoidCall()).andReturn(20).atLeastOnce();
      expectLastCall().anyTimes();

      ClassUnderTest a=new ClassUnderTest ();
      a.getRecord();
      replayAll();
      PowerMock.verify();
}

}
```

Basically I want the output as below

```
1: In getRecord

2: In ArpitSecondClass getVoidCall for kv testing

3:20 (Note:This should be overriden by the value I supplied in UnitTest) 

4: In getRecord over
```

But the output which I am getting with the Unitest code is

```
2: In ArpitSecondClass getVoidCall for kv testing
```

The code flow doesnt go beyond expect(class2.getVoidCall()).andReturn(20).atLeastOnce();

And the remaining statments in getRecord are not printed as it's never called at all.

Am I missing something here ?

Comment: Using static method is a bad practice since it hides the classes dependencies and makes your code inflexible and hard to reuse. So instead of surrendering to you bad design and using *PowerMock* you should remove the `static` key word from the method in `ArpitSecondClass` and pass an instance of this class as constructor parameter to your class under test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SecondClass#getVoidCall()` method (`public static int getVoidCall() {...}`) is a `static` method and, as such, the mocking is a little different.

Replace the first two lines:

```
@Test
public void testMock() throws Exception {
    SecondClass class2 = createMock(SecondClass.class);
    expect(class2.getVoidCall()).andReturn(20).atLeastOnce();
```

With the lines below (and prepare the class):

```
import static org.easymock.EasyMock.expect;
import static org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.mockStatic;
...

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({TestArpit.class, SecondClass.class})       // added SecondClass.class here
public class UniteTestClass {

    @Test
    public void testMock() throws Exception {
        mockStatic(SecondClass.class);                                 // changed this line
        expect(SecondClass.getVoidCall()).andReturn(20).atLeastOnce(); // changed this line
```

Comment: Worked with ease .Thank you so much